Why is it ‘lived’ instead of ‘live’ in: "I'm surprised I lived”?
My first language isn't English, so I'm confused why people use lived instead of live in sentences like:

I'm surprised I lived.

I know that lived is past tense but I don’t understand why they use it in situations that just happened.
I just cant wrap my head around it. He is surprised that he is living even tho something happened that he should not survived and not that he was alive or I'm I wrong?
Thanks for responses

In fact you're correctly using the past tense in your own answer. You wrote in situations that just happened. (Not happens) Five minutes ago and five years ago are both in the past, so a past tense is valid in both cases.

Yeah but the problem is he is still living and not that they were living. Im sorry if it doesn't make sense, i cant explain myself in english xd.

No worries. You're doing well. Think of the tenses as tools to say what you need to say. "Last year I lived with my parents. This year I am living in my own home." The past tense here is used even though I'm living now, because the first sentence is not talking about now, it's talking about an earlier time in my life.

i just cant wrap my head around it. He is surprised that he is living even tho something happened that he should not survived and not that he was alive or im i wrong ? if im wrong i will just accept it xd

Again: Don't think of it as right or wrong, because it depends on what you want to say. Sentence 1 - I am surprised that I lived through the earthquake. Sentence 2 - I am surprised that I am still alive after the earthquake. Both of those sentences are correct, because one is talking about being alive then, and the other is talking about being alive now.


I'm surprised I lived.

The surprise suggests there was a threat to life, but that the speaker did not die. Thus, "I lived" has the meaning "I survived" not "I am alive now". Although the two meanings are practically the same (the speaker's heart is still beating and the speaker is able to speak, etc etc), the practical fact can be expressed in different ways:

I survived that threat. That threat did not kill me.
I am alive now despite that threat.

One speaks of the past incident. The other speaks of the present.
